# Making a copy pasting script with autopy

Tags: python, for-loop, copy-paste

```
def copypaste():
    x = 289
    y = range(x, 700, 40)
    z = 289+53
    a = range(z, 700, 20)
    b = 289+121
    c = range(b, 700, 20)
    for x in y:
        mouse.smooth_move(376, x)
        clickthrice()
        mouse.click(3)
        mouse.smooth_move(400, x+11)
        mouse.click()
        for z in a:
            mouse.smooth_move(903, z)
            mouse.click()
            mouse.click(3)
        for b in c:
            mouse.smooth_move(927, b)
            mouse.click()
```

I'm trying to copy one column list visible in the desktop and paste it in another location also in the form of a specific list. one by one.
The problem is that it runs all of the second "for loop" for each item in the list of y. The third "for loop" also runs as a whole for each item in the list of y. I need the second and third "for loop" items to run hand in hand with each of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hand in hand" would only work when you have equal elements in both `a` and `c`. After making them equal you can use -

```
for z,b in zip(a,c):
    mouse.smooth_move(903, z)
    mouse.click()
    mouse.click(3)
    mouse.smooth_move(927, b)
    mouse.click()
```

Comment: thanks for introducing me this function. i meant z and b "hand in hand" with x.

Comment: @user2526448 you can extend this similarly to the desired case. Like `for x,z,b in zip(y,a,b):`

Comment: yeah. i figured that out and completed my desired script.

Comment: @user2526448 Great. Accept my answer if you think it helped.